# How to divide text file in chunks so that every chunk I can proceed with individual thread

Tags: string, vb.net, multithreading, file, text-files

I want to divide one textfile in 5 total chunks. So that I can use one thread on one chunk and so on. i wrote a code in vb.net but if total lines in textfile is  multiple of 5 then only my code cover full textfile lines. Please guide me in this.

```
 Private Function breakTextFile(ByVal path As String)
        Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(path)
        Dim sizeOfFile As Integer = allLines.Length
        Dim break As Integer = 5, counter As Integer = 0, startline As Integer = 0
        Dim index As Integer = sizeOfFile / break
        Dim endline As Integer = 0
        endline = index
        Dim listOfStringArray As New List(Of ArrayList)
        Do While (counter <= break)
            Dim chunk As New ArrayList
            For i = startline To (endline - 1)
                Chunk.Add(allLines(i))
            Next
            listOfStringArray.Add(chunk)
            startline = endline
            endline = startline + index
            counter = counter + 1
        Loop
        Return listOfStringArray
    End Function
```

Comment: Have the lines in your file the same length?

Comment: You can use morelinq's Batch method https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs

Comment: Steve: No. All individual string line is different

Comment: @L.B: Thanks for your input. if possible could you please guide me in above code.

Comment: `var chunks = File.ReadLines(path).Batch(5).ToList();` Every chunk will have (totalLines/5) lines.

Comment: var chunks = File.ReadLines(path).Batch(5).ToList(); I didnt get you in this. Your Batch is written in C# and mine is VB.net How supposed to integrate into it. If you can suggest in my above code what would be the logic, then is very helpful for me.

Comment: @Neel download the package using nuget and use it VB.

Comment: Dim chunks = File.ReadLines(path).Batch(5).ToList()

Comment: @L.B: Thanks for your input. Cud you please tell me which package i have to install through Nuget. Because I can see in Visual studio 2015. Right click on my project Name form Solution Explorer --> Manage NuGet pacakges. I am seeing many default packages. So which package will help me to download and install your Batch.cs file??

Comment: @Neel search for `morelinq`

Comment: @L.B: Thank you so much for your input. It is work for me.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports MoreLinq

Private Function breakTextFile(ByVal path As String)
        Dim listOfStringArray As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of String))
        listOfStringArray = File.ReadLines(textFilePath).Batch(10000).ToList()
        Return listOfStringArray
    End Function
```